# Passing selected dropdown value to query string in an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How to pass the selected value from select tag to anchor tag as a query string so that it can be accessible on other php page?
I want to do something like this:

```
<select name="category">
<option></option>
</select>
<a href="category.php?selected='category.value'></a>
```

What is the right way to do that? I am using [html](/questions/tagged/html) and [php](/questions/tagged/php).

Comment: What you are talking about is meant by [tag:javascript]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
    $('[name="category"]').change(function(){

   var href = $(this).val(); 
    $('.linkhere').attr('href','category.php?selected='+href);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gw8wk3vp/

Comment: Mention the OP that is a [tag:jquery] solution.

Comment: can we do this in simple html anchor tag without using javascript or jquery

Comment: No, php doesn't change client side like Javascript or jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Using plain JavaScript, I'd suggest:

```
// a named function to handle the change event:
function addValueToURL() {

  // this (in this demo the <select> element) passed
  // automatically from the addEventListener() method;
  // here we encode the value of the <select> using
  // encodeURIComponent() to ensure the value will
  // be made up of URL-safe/valid characters:
  var value = encodeURIComponent(this.value),

      // getting a reference to the <a> element that you
      // want to update:
      anchor = this.nextElementSibling;

  // the HTMLAnchorElement's search property,
  // the portion of a URL following the '?'
  // is here set to the string 'category='
  // followed by the URI-encoded value from
  // the <select>:
  anchor.search = 'category=' + value;
}

// getting a reference to the first element that matches
// the CSS selector, selecting a <select> element with a
// name-attribute equal to 'category':
var select = document.querySelector('select[name=category]'),

    // creating a new Event (with the same name as an
    // existing event) in order to trigger that event
    // when the page loads:
    changeEvent = new Event('change');

// binding the function as the event-handler
// for the 'change' event:
select.addEventListener('change', addValueToURL);

// triggering the 'change' event:
select.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
```

With the CSS:

```
a::before {
  content: attr(href);
}
```

The CSS is entirely irrelevant to the functionality, it just allows you to see the changes in the URL of the `<a>` element as they happen.

```js
function addValueToURL(event) {
  var value = encodeURIComponent(this.value),
    anchor = this.nextElementSibling;
  anchor.search = 'category=' + value;
}

var select = document.querySelector('select[name=category]'),
  changeEvent = new Event('change');

select.addEventListener('change', addValueToURL);
select.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
```

```css
a::before {
  content: attr(href);
}
```

```html
<select name="category">
  <option value="option1">Option One</option>
  <option value="option2">Option Two</option>
  <option value="option3">Option Three</option>
  <option value="option4">Option Four</option>
</select>
<a href="http://exampledomain.com"></a>
```

With regards to your [comment elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30196047/passing-selected-dropdown-value-to-query-string-in-an-anchor-tag/30197135#comment48498777_30196374):

> can we do this in simple html anchor tag without using [JavaScript]…

No, at least not currently

> …or [jQuery]

Absolutely, yes; jQuery is *never* a requirement, it's simply a library of JavaScript which makes it easier to write simple cross-browser compatible code (the library handles the cross-browser problems transparently, so that the author doesn't have to worry about it).

References:

- CSS:

  - [CSS pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).
- JavaScript:

  - [Creating and Triggering Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).
  - [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent).
  - [`HTMLAnchorElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement).
  - [`NonDocumentTypeChildNode.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling).
  - [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement).